# how to get particular products from collection in magento

Tags: products, magento-1

for example my store has 20 products. I load all products using following code

```
$collection = Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product')->getCollection()->addAttributeToSelect('*')->addAttributeToSort('name','ASC');
```

In ascending order they list a product from number 1,2,3,...20.

how i get products which are numbered 8,9,10..15.

Comment: what are 8 and 15?

Comment: @Guest follow Quaisar answer for more check this : https://www.creare.co.uk/blog/magento/limiting-collection-size-in-magento

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
/** @var Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Collection $collection */
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();
$collection->addAttributeToSelect('*')
    ->addAttributeToSort('name','ASC');
$collection->getSelect()->limit(8,7);
$items = $collection->getItems();
echo count($items); // or something else
```

Answer (score 1):

this will do trick for you

```
$collection = Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product')->getCollection()->addAttributeToSelect('*')->addAttributeToSort('name','ASC')
$collection->getSelect()->limit(7,8);
```